# Matlab - Plot sequence of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, sequence

I have a sequence of matrices I've created like this:

```
for i=1:n
Real{i}=Real_Trans^i;
Trans{i}=Trans_Est^i;
R{i}=abs(Real{i}-Trans{i});
end
```

where the user inputs n.
Now, I want to plot lines for each element of every matrix R{i}.
So, for example, let's take element (1,1). I need to get (1,1) from each matrix and make a line with them. Another line for all (1,2)'s. And keep going like that.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you had a 3D-array instead of a cell array of 2d-arrays.

Anyway, with your data `R`, you can use:

```
plot(reshape(cat(3, R{:}), [], numel(R)).', 'o-')
```

This exploits the fact that, according to [`plot`'s documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html),

> `plot(Y)` plots the columns of Y versus their index.

Example: let's create 5 matrices of size 2x3:

```
for n = 1:5
    R{n} = randn(2,3);
end
```

Then the above code produces the following figure:

[image]

Comment: That does exactly what I need it to. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hmm, I get this though, when    `n > matrix size`    :
    
`Error using reshape
    Product of known dimensions, 100, not divisible into total     number of elements, 64.

    Error in difplot (line 16)
        plot(reshape(cat(3, R{:}), [], n).', 'o-');`

Comment: What are matrix sizes and `n` when it fails?

Comment: matrix size is 8x8 in this example and it seems like I can only use   numbers that divide 8x8=64 as n. 50 and 100 fail. 1, 2, 32, 64 work

Comment: @integral `for n = 1:50, R{n} = randn(8,8); end` does work for me. I think my code works for any `n` regardless of matrix size. Perhaps your `n` is not the same as `numel(R)`? I have replaced `n` by `numel(R)` in my answer for greater clarity

Comment: numel(R) seems to be the same as n, so no problem there. Still it doesn't work. The code is exactly as given in the original question.
The one you said does work though

Comment: If I replace n with numel(R), I get this

`Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 4096, not divisible into total number of elements, 64.`

regardless of n

Comment: also, on another example with 2x2 matrices, I can only use n=1, 2 or 4. Nothing else.

Comment: Got it. My bad. I had the plot command inside the loop. Sorry about that :P. Everything works perfect now.